# Running powershell script against specific OU in AD

Tags: powershell, active-directory, powershell-3.0

```
import-module activedirectory    
$DaysInactive = 90   
$time = (Get-Date).Adddays(-($DaysInactive))  
Get-ADComputer -Filter {LastLogonTimeStamp -lt $time} -Properties LastLogonTimeStamp |   

select-object Name,@{Name="Stamp"; Expression={[DateTime]::FromFileTime($_.lastLogonTimestamp)}} | export-csv C:\users\user\desktop\OLD_Computer.csv
    -notypeinformation
```

This is the script I am trying to run to clean up some stale objects within Active Directory.  I am tracking down computer objects that have not been logged into in the last 90 days or longer.  This script works fine, but now I need to run it against a specific OU, I know I need to put a searchbase somewhere - but I am unsure where it needs to be placed.

```
-SearchBase ou=workstations,dc=,dc=
```

Thanks in advance for all your help, you guys are always great.

Comment: It's a parameter of `Get-ADComputer`, so same statement as `-Filter` and `-Properties`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen - Best not to answer in comments; propose it as a formal answer.

Comment: Why was this downvoted?

Comment: @arcset  Lol I have no clue

Answer (score 0):

thanks for taking the time to respond, sorry for the people that got upset over this question.  I was missing the quotes around my parameter - it works now.